# JQuery binding to object method via closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code. Obviously what I want is for the method `window.xl.timectrl.Tuio.prototype.tcHour12Changed` to get called when `this.hour12` gets changed. I'm absolutely sure `this.hour12` refers to an actual select box, but nothing happens when I change it. What is wrong here?

```
window.xl.timectrl.Tuio = function(label_base, update_ui){
    this.update_ui = update_ui;
    this.hour12 = $('#' + label_base + '_hour12');
    this.hour12.off('change').on('change', getSelectBoxHandler(this.hour12, $.proxy(this.tcHour12Changed), this));
}

window.xl.timectrl.Tuio.prototype.tcHour12Changed = function(event, ui, value, id){
    //handle event
    this.update_ui();
}

function getSelectBoxHandler(select_box, onchange){
    var handler = function(event, ui){
        var id = select_box.attr('id');
        var value = select_box.find('option:selected').attr('value');
        onchange(event, ui, value, id);
    }
    return handler;
}
```

The point here is for `getSelectBoxHandler()` to return a handler which is bound to the particular select box and provided handler with a closure. When this returned handler is called when the select box is changed, it will know both the select box to extract the current value from, and the actual onchange handler to pass the value to, in this case, `window.xl.timectrl.Tuio.prototype.tcHour12Changed()`. i would like this actual handler to have access to members of the object, like `this.update_ui()`, which is why I wanted the actual handler to be a member of the object instead of a stand-alone function.

This way, this code that extracts the value from the select box does not have to be repeated in every handler, and no explicit call to any function has to be in every such handler to do this work. This approach has worked fine with stand-alone functions, but broke when I tried to use an object member as the handler. I am very interested in why this doesn't work.

Comment: If this is a copy and past of your code, then you should have an error in the console complaining about `GetSelectBoxHandler` not being defined as you define it with a lowercase `g`.

Comment: `getSelectBoxHandler` appears to take two arguments, but you are passing three in `Tuio`. I believe you want the `, this` to be inside the `$.proxy()` call, no?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working, but not exactly how you have it written. When doing the `.on('change',...)` part, I couldn't call the `getSelectBoxHandler` function and pass arguments. If you remove the arguments, for example:

```
this.hour12.off('change').on('change', getSelectBoxHandler);
```

Then it started working, but obvously didn't accomplish your goal. So I used an anonymous function instead:

```
window.xl.timectrl.Tuio = function (label_base, update_ui) {
    this.hour12 = $('#' + label_base + '_hour12');

    this.hour12.off('change').on('change', function () {
        getSelectBoxHandler(this.hour12, $.proxy(this.tcHour12Changed), this);
    });
}
```

Seems to be working correctly, fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mey9LzLw/

Comment: To further explain this answer, you were creating an event handler on change with the return value of `getSelectBoxHandler()` instead of what you wanted, which is to call `getSelectBoxHandler` on change.

Comment: Thanks, but actually, creating the onchange handler with the `getSelectBoxHandler()` function was exactly what I was trying to do. I wanted to return a handler that could extract the value of the select box it gets from this returned function's closure, and then pass that value to a member function i passed in as onchange, which has access to the other members of the object. I apologize that it was not obvious what I was attempting to do, and I updated the question accordingly.